# Undeclared Identifier error in Pinescript while updating to version=4

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am trying to convert Ehlers Instantaneous Trend study script to v=4 but getting Undeclared Identifier error in version=4

The original script can be found here -

https://www.tradingview.com/script/DaHLcICg-Ehlers-Instantaneous-Trend-LazyBear/

```
study(title="Ehlers Instantaneous Trend [LazyBear]", shorttitle="EIT_LB", overlay=true, precision=3)
src=input(hl2, title="Source")
a= input(0.07, title="Alpha", step=0.01) 
fr=input(false, title="Fill Trend Region")
ebc=input(false, title="Enable barcolors")
hr=input(false, title="Hide Ribbon")
it=(a-((a*a)/4.0))*src+0.5*a*a*src[1]-(a-0.75*a*a)*src[2]+2*(1-a )*nz(it[1], ((src+2*src[1]+src[2])/4.0))-(1-a )*(1-a )*nz(it[2], ((src+2*src[1]+src[2])/4.0))
lag=2.0*it-nz(it[2])
dl=plot(fr and (not hr)?(it>lag?lag:it):na, color=gray, style=circles, linewidth=0, title="Dummy")
itl=plot(hr?na:it, color=fr?gray:red, linewidth=1, title="Trend")
ll=plot(hr?na:lag, color=fr?gray:blue, linewidth=1, title="Trigger")
fill(dl, ll, green, title="UpTrend", transp=70)
fill(dl, itl, red, title="DownTrend", transp=70)
bc=not ebc?na:(it>lag?red:lime)
barcolor(bc)
```

errors

```
Processing script...
line 9: Undeclared identifier `it`;
line 10: Undeclared identifier `it`;
line 11: Undeclared identifier `it`;
line 11: Undeclared identifier `lag`;
line 12: Undeclared identifier `it`;
line 13: Undeclared identifier `lag`;
line 16: Undeclared identifier `it`;
line 16: Undeclared identifier `lag`;
line 17: Undeclared identifier `bc`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Trying to base a strategy on the script.

Have a nice day

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study(title="Ehlers Instantaneous Trend [LazyBear]", shorttitle="EIT_LB", overlay=true, precision=3)

src = input(hl2, title="Source")
a   = input(0.07, title="Alpha", step=0.01) 
fr  = input(false, title="Fill Trend Region")
ebc = input(false, title="Enable barcolors")
hr  = input(false, title="Hide Ribbon")

var float it = na

it  := (a-((a*a)/4.0))*src+0.5*a*a*src[1]-(a-0.75*a*a)*src[2]+2*(1-a )*nz(it[1], ((src+2*src[1]+src[2])/4.0))-(1-a )*(1-a )*nz(it[2], ((src+2*src[1]+src[2])/4.0))
lag = 2.0*it-nz(it[2])
dl  = plot(fr and (not hr)?(it>lag?lag:it):na, color=color.gray, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0, title="Dummy")
itl = plot(hr?na:it, color=fr?color.gray:color.red, linewidth=1, title="Trend")
ll  = plot(hr?na:lag, color=fr?color.gray:color.blue, linewidth=1, title="Trigger")

fill(dl, ll, color.new(color.green, 70), title="UpTrend")
fill(dl, itl, color.new(color.red, 70), title="DownTrend")

bc  = not ebc?na:(it>lag?color.red:color.lime)
barcolor(bc)
```